# Inserting dataframe rows into SQL database

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I'm trying to insert every row of my pandas dataframe (called close) into a sql database. I tried multiple codes but nothing seems to work... Here are details on my code:

```
close = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    close = pd.read_json('https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/'+t+'/chart/max?token='+token+'')
    close['ticker']=t
close

parameters = (row['date'],row['ticker'])

for index,row in close.iterrows():
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Stocks (date, ticker) VALUES (?,?)''',parameters)
    cur.fetchall
    mydb.commit()
cur.close()
```

I expected to get the date and ticker values saved into the database but that didn't happen. I got this message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-105-245f75b8336d> in <module>
          3 
          4 for index,row in close.iterrows():
    ----> 5     cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Stocks (date, ticker) VALUES (?,?)''',parameters)
          6     cur.fetchall
          7     mydb.commit()

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I know the problem is in the INSERT function because when I run the code with parameters = (1,2) it works...

Comment: Could you please provide minimum reproducible code? ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ). What is tickets, what is token? Where is the 'row' coming from when you wrote: parameters = (row['date'],row['ticker'])  ? Also, why are you recreating a new version of dataframe 'close' in each iteration of the for loop. Could you please help with the details of your 'close' dataframe that you are trying to build? Also, what is the DBMS to which you are trying to write to? Is 'mydb' your connection object? What is the reason of cur.fetchall  ?